# Uncaught TypeError: THREE.ShaderPass is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I just started using three.js, but I had a problem in the library, I included everything on HTML file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>spacemen</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r124/three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://baronwatts.com/scripts/LegacyJSONLoader.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.0/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.5/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
  <!-- processing -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/postprocessing/RenderPass.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/postprocessing/MaskPass.js"></script>
  <!-- shaders -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/shaders/CopyShader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/shaders/HorizontalTiltShiftShader.js"></script>
  <!-- https://github.com/a-jie/threejs-geometry-modifiers -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://unpkg.com/three.modifiers@2.1.0"></script>
  <!-- cannon -->
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/schteppe/cannon.js/master/build/cannon.js"></script>

  <div id="info"></div>
    <script type="module" src="src/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and even that i got a problem said that THREE.ShaderPass is not a constructor :

main.js:426 Uncaught TypeError: THREE.ShaderPass is not a constructor
at main.js:426:13

here is the part of this problem in the JS file :

```js
var SCALE = 2;

var hTilt = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.HorizontalTiltShiftShader);
hTilt.enabled = false;
hTilt.uniforms.h.value = 4 / (SCALE * window.innerHeight);

var renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera);
var effectCopy = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.CopyShader);
effectCopy.renderToScreen = true;

var composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);
composer.addPass(renderPass);
composer.addPass(hTilt);
composer.addPass(effectCopy);
```

Comment: Is `ShaderPass.js` loaded at the time you run your code? If it has `type=module` I think it's no longer loaded sequentially? Or maybe there's a CORS issue?

Comment: I changed the type from text/javascript to module and i get the same error , when i delete SharedPass declaration from the code they gave me another error that RenderPass is not a constructor, the same thing for ShaderPass and EffectComposer

Comment: I was thinking more on the lines of running your code with a delay or through an event handler, or putting it or a part of it in a script that is not a module.

Comment: How can i run the code with a delay ?

Comment: I created a 'main.js' in which I just put one line:`console.log(THREE.ShaderPass)`; it displays the right thing `class ShaderPass { .... ` Does your script display the same thing?

Comment: Hello, when i put console.log(THREE.ShaderPass), it gave me the same problem: Uncaught TypeError: THREE.ShaderPass is not a constructor

Comment: Well, as I said, I copied the html you pasted in your question, I excluded `style.css`, and created a 'src/main.js' file that contains *just* `console.log(THREE.ShaderPass)` and it works as expected from my local server.

Comment: See this [replit](https://three.kikon.repl.co/) - it's basically your code from above

Comment: I found it, it was a problem of imporation of libraries, so what i did is remove the first line in main.js which is an import of THREE Library.thank you for your help i aperciate it <3